# Getting PID from within a Start-Job

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble getting the PID from a Start-Process within a Start-Job in Powershell (latest version).  The Start-Process cmdlet runs and returns the PID as expected when run outside of the Start-Job Scriptblock. When the statement is added to the Start-Job Scriptblock, no PID is returned.  Can someone point this newbie in the right direction?

```bsh
$myJob = Start-Job -Name newJob -ScriptBlock {
$procID = (Start-Process myprogram.exe -PassThru -ArgumentList "myArgs" -WorkingDirectory "myWorkingDir").Id
}
```

Comment: I should add that there may be multiple instances of myprogram.exe running; therefore, Get-Process -Name myprogram.exe  | select Id will not work in this case.

Comment: Well, you assign the process id value to `$procID` and never do anything with it. Remove `$procID =` and the job result should be the process ID of `myprogram.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you think that assigning to a variable in a script block being executed in a background job makes that variable visible to the *caller*, which is *not* the case.

[Background jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Jobs) run in an entirely separate session, and, **in order to communicate data to the *caller*, the success *output stream* must be used, whose content the caller must collect via the [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job) cmdlet**:

```
$myJob = Start-Job -Name newJob -ScriptBlock {
  # Implicitly output the PID of the asynchronously launched process,
  # by using -PassThru and returning the output object's .Id property value.
  # Note: By default, Start-Process runs the process 
  #       *asynchronously*, in a *new window*.
  (
    Start-Process myprogram.exe -PassThru -ArgumentList "myArgs" -WorkingDirectory "myWorkingDir"
  ).Id
}

# Use Receive-Job to collect the background job's output, once available, 
# then remove the job automatically.
# Note: The process launched *asynchronously* from the background job
#       with Start-Process lives on.
$procId = Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Taking a step back: **`Start-Process` is *itself* asynchronous, so there's no need to use a background job**: just start `myprogram.exe` directly in the caller's context:

```
# Launch myprogram.exe asynchronously, in a new window.
# $proc receives a value once the program has *launched* and
# your script continues right after.
$proc = Start-Process myprogram.exe -PassThru -ArgumentList "myArgs" -WorkingDirectory "myWorkingDir"

# $proc.Id retrieves the PID (process ID)
# $proc.HasExited tells you whether the process has exited.
# $proc.WaitForExit() allows you to wait synchronously for the process to exit.
#   * If you intend to wait *right away*, i.e run in a new window, but
#     in a blocking fashion, you can omit -PassThru and pass -Wait instead.
```

However, **if `myprogram.exe` is a *console* (terminal) application that you want to run *asynchronously* and whose *output you want to capture***, do use `Start-Job`, but don't use `Start-Process` to launch `myprogram.exe`: invoke it *directly* from the background job:

```
$myJob = Start-Job -Name newJob -ScriptBlock {
  Set-Location "myWorkingDir"
  # Launch console app myprogram.exe *synchronously*, *invisibly*,
  # and relay its (stdout) output as the job's output. 
  myprogram.exe
}

# ... do other things

# Wait for myprogram.exe to finish, at which point the
# job exits, relaying its (stdout) output.
$myJob | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```